# Check password for ethereum wallet

Tags: wallet, ethereum

I have an Ethereum wallet and wish to check if some password was used to create it.
How this could be done?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Ethereum stackexchange site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could check by starting a [geth console](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) and using the [personal.unlockAccount](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#personalunlockaccount) function:

```
$ geth console
> personal.unlockAccount("address", "password")
```

Comment: Ummm so I unlocked it... Do I need to lock it again, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: The account should be automatically locked after few seconds.

personal.unlockAccount(addr, passwd, duration)

Unlock the account with the given address, password and an optional duration (in seconds). If password is not given you will be prompted for it.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible with [pyethsaletool](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethsaletool/blob/master/pyethsaletool.py):

```
./pyethsaletool recover -w your-wallet.json -p password
```

In case of password failure it will throw something like

```
ValueError: String ending with 'X' can't be PCKS7-padded
```

If password is valid, it will show your seed (long string of random characters).

Actually `pyethsaletool` uses supplied password to AES-decrypt `encseed` field from the wallet. This seed is SHA3-hashed to get private key and ethereum address which is compared to the one from the wallet.

Answer (score 3):

You could use MyEtherWallet.com to check your password. Go to the "[View Wallet Info](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info)" section and select your keystore file (the wallet file with .json at the end). Enter the right password. If it shows "Success! Here are your wallet details." you have the right password.

Comment: This looks like a scam.  I advise anyone reading this to NOT upload your wallet file and give a website your password.

Comment: No, MyEtherWallet.com is legit. You don't upload anything. It processes your keys client-side. If you don't trust it, you can download it from git and use your own copy locally: https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet

Comment: @5chdn, thanks for the clarification.  You have to admit, this looked very sketchy.

Comment: @5chdn is right. I corrected the sloppy choice of words in my answer and replaced "upload" with "select". The file is not uploaded but processed client-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Parity Ethereum Wallet, it has a *test password* feature: [parity.io](https://parity.io). You can either use the `parity_testPassword` [RPC call](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity_accounts-module#parity_testpassword):

```
curl --data '{"method":"parity_testPassword","params":["0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1","hunter2"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
```

Or use the graphical wallet interface and go to Accounts > Open the Account in question > Click password and chose "Test".

<sup>*Disclosure: I work for Parity.*</sup>